# How to overpass the error 403 HTTP request method not allowed

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login into my account, at a stock exchange website, so I can retrieve some of my privacy information over the time. Could someone help me to overpass the problem I'm facing?

I've been trying something with requests, as it follows:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://fakepath.com.br',
    'Referer': 'https://fakepath.com.br/login',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36',
}

login_data = {
    'email': 'login',
    'password': 'password',
    'modulo': '2',
    'empresaId': '0',
}

with requests.session() as s:
    url = "https://fakepath.com.br/login"
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    #print(r.content)

    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

    print(r.content)
```

And the network request when login is:

```
General:
Request URL: https://fakepath.com.br/auth
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 35.167.224.228:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers:
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: BBCE-XAUTH,BBCE-USER,Content-Type
access-control-allow-methods: POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Tue, 14 May 2019 18:45:58 GMT
server: Kestrel
status: 200
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Request Headers:
Provisional headers are shown
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Origin: https://fakepath.com.br
Referer: https://fakepath.com.br/login
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36

Form Data:
email: login
password: password
modulo: 2
empresaId: 0
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
b'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size="1px">\nThis distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.\n\n<BR clear="all">\n<HR noshade size="1px">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: 9BribBZzu94aROtVCcWJLluXyum8k70iAqwEHO5AMYGKEUHRu1SaHA==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending the POST request to the wrong URL try replacing this line:

```
r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

with this one:

```
r = s.post("https://fakepath.com.br/auth", data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

hope this helps